# An error in building code in stm32 cube ide (make: error)

Tags: robotics, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4, stm32cubeide

I'm trying to build code in stm32f401ccu6 blackpill but I keep getting this error :

> make: ***[Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/subdir.mk:61: Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o] Error 1

This is the log from console tab.

> 15:51:00 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project WHY ****
> make -j4 all
> arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F401xC -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.o"
> arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F401xC -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o"
> arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F401xC -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.o"
> arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F401xC -c -I../Core/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.o"
> arm-none-eabi-gcc: fatal error: cannot execute 'd:/robocon/stm32cubeide_1.10.1/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/as.exe': CreateProcess: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.
> arm-none-eabi-gcc: fatal error: cannot execute 'd:/robocon/stm32cubeide_1.10.1/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/as.exe': CreateProcess: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.
> arm-none-eabi-gcc: fatal error: cannot execute 'd:/robocon/stm32cubeide_1.10.1/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/as.exe': CreateProcess: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.
> arm-none-eabi-gcc: fatal error: cannot execute 'd:/robocon/stm32cubeide_1.10.1/stm32cubeide/plugins/com.st.stm32cube.ide.mcu.externaltools.gnu-tools-for-stm32.10.3-2021.10.win32_1.0.0.202111181127/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/as.exe': CreateProcess: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.
> make: *** [Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/subdir.mk:61: Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal.o] Error 1
> make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
> make: *** [Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/subdir.mk:61: Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o] Error 1
> make: *** [Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/subdir.mk:61: Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.o] Error 1
> make: *** [Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/subdir.mk:61: Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_dma.o] Error 1
> "make -j4 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
> 15:51:00 Build Failed. 5 errors, 0 warnings. (took 718ms)

What does that error code mean and is there any applicable solution that I can use?

I expected my code to built, but it turns out the error keeps coming and I don't know what to do.